# Using generic interface in the constraint of another generic class declaration

Tags: delphi, generics

Using Delphi 10 Seattle, is it possible to use a generic interface as the interface constraint of another generic class definition?

I have this interface declaration:

```
IrmOpenAPIConfigurationItemRequest<REQUESTDATA, RESPONSE> = interface(IrmOpenAPIRequest)
  procedure DoSomething;
end;
```

I want to declare a generic class with the above type as a constraint, so I can use the DoSomething method in the implementation of TBaseConfigItem_Model.

```
TBaseConfigItem_Model<REQUEST: IrmOpenAPIConfigurationItemRequest<REQUESTDATA, RESPONSE>> = class(...);
```

This gives the compile error: Undeclared identifier 'REQUESTDATA'

How can I accomplish this?

P.S. Some implementation details are left out for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use a generic interface as a constraint, but you do need to introduce the missing generic parameters. That is what the compiler error message is telling you. The following compiles:

```
type
  TBaseConfigItem_Model<REQUESTDATA; RESPONSE; REQUEST: 
    IrmOpenAPIConfigurationItemRequest<REQUESTDATA, RESPONSE>> = class
  public
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it actually does compile but breaks the need for the REQUEST parameter as I can now declare a variable of type ; IrmOpenAPIConfigurationItemRequest<REQUESTDATA, RESPONSE>

Comment: Remember that I can only see what is in the question and don't have the bigger picture that you have. I think I answered the question you asked, no?

Comment: Oh, and thanks for correcting my syntax in the generic constraint. I always forget that issue. Perhaps that's what you meant by your comment.

Comment: Does it work with class as a constraint too? e.g. I have a generic class definition like this: `TShape<TVertexType: TVertex>` so can I declare another generic class like: `TModel<TVertexType; TShape<TVertexType>>`? It doesn't compile. I want to enforce that any child class of TModel<...> must use a child class of  TShape<TVertexType>.